# Unable to get growl_notify to work on Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, growlnotify

When I run guard, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Error sending notification with growl_notify: undefined method
>   `first' for nil:NilClass

My gemfile includes:

```
group :test, :development do
    gem 'turn'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'growl_notify'
end
```

Growl version: 1.3.2
Ruby version: 1.8.7

Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

With growl_notify you tend to send something like:

`GrowlNotify.normal(:title => 'HELLO WORLD', :description => 'Man that was cool')`

I guessing you are trying to use some array and access the first element like this:

`GrowlNotify.normal(:title => 'HELLO WORLD', :description => "#{someArray.first()}")`

and someArray is nil.